# file_get_content get the wrong web

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am learning to spider website contents with PHP-`file_get_contents`,but something is wrong.The web I want is "http://www.jandan.net".

But use `file_get_content()`,I get the contents from "http://i.jandan.net" (it's phone page, they are different pages). `user_agent` is also unusable.

```
<?php
ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100301 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.6");
$url = 'http://www.jandan.net/';
/*
$opt = array( 'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\n"
)
);
$context = stream_context_create($opt);
*/
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo var_dump($content);
?>
```

Comment: Both URLs are working fine for me. Or am I misinterpreting those Chinese 404 pages?

Comment: Have you looked into using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) instead of file_get_contents? Changing the useragent with curl is pretty simple if it becomes an issue. _curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '')_

Comment: *"But use file_get_content()"* it's `file_get_contents()` ;-) plus try removing that comma in `($url,)` that alone will throw an error.

Comment: @AmalMurali You mean, you didn't get a parse error when using the OP's code as is? => `($url,)`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I did, but I just (blindly) assumed that it was just a typing mistake.

Comment: @AmalMurali It's so hard to tell if the OP made a typo. I tested the OP's code and removed the comma and posted it as answer, wondering/hoping that's all it was. Hard to say at this point in time.

Comment: @AmalMurali @Fred-ii- sorry,I'm supposed to type `$content = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);` ,it's just a mistake. The two URLs can be both usable,but there are some tiny difference .What I doubt is if the web has two distinct pages, ONE is PC page, ONE is MOBILE page(my problem is that I type the PC URL but it skip to MOBILE site), _how can I visit the PC page instead of the MOBILE page with PHP?_ I guess if there is nothing wrong in my code, specially `ini_set('user_agent',...)`,the fault may result from the PHP environment（I use the SAE web servers which has its own class FetchURL）

Answer (score 0):

Your comma in `$content = file_get_contents($url,);` is causing the problem.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------^

## From [original posted code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18362048/1) ---^

Keeping the comma will produce the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in.....(folder path etc.)

**Quick note**: Using `$url = 'http://i.jandan.net/';` worked also, got content displayed.

Try this:

```
<?php
ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100301 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.6");
$url = 'http://www.jandan.net/';

/*
$opt = array( 'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\n"
)
);
$context = stream_context_create($opt);
*/
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo var_dump($content);
// echo $content;
?>
```