# PHP file_get_contents/curl - getting different result than browser

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get content of this page: http://www.nytimes.com/2014/01/26/us/politics/rand-pauls-mixed-inheritance.html?hp&_r=0

I tried `file_get_contents` and `curl` solution but all gives me a Login page of NYTimes and I have no idea why.

Tried these [file_get_contents()/curl getting unexpected page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553346/file-get-contents-curl-getting-unexpected-page), [PHP file_get_contents() behaves differently to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548451/php-file-get-contents-behaves-differently-to-browser), [file_get_content get the wrong web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362048/file-get-content-get-the-wrong-web)

Is there any solution? Thanks

EDIT:

```
    //this is the curl code I use
    $cookieJar = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026     Firefox/3.6.12');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data    = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: On the server you are running this code on, does "curl http://www.nytimes.com/2014/01/26/us/politics/rand-pauls-mixed-inheritance.html?hp&_r=0" output the right information?

Comment: They could be blocking access by domain (to prevent scraping) in their server settings such as .htaccess

Comment: Did you pass an agent?

Comment: nytimes is definitely blocking scrapers. You'll have to tinker with the cURL flags to get it to appear as if it's a browser. I'm not a cURL pro; I wish I could help more. Best of luck :)

Comment: @enigma I passed `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026     Firefox/3.6.12');`

Comment: Then edit that in the question, not here in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to test it using saving cookies to same directory where the script resides first
so set the cookies path like that
$cookie = "cookie.txt";
this code works with me and i got the page

```
<?php
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
$get_page = curl_get_contents("http://www.nytimes.com/2014/01/26/us/politics/rand-pauls-mixed-inheritance.html?hp&_r=1");
echo $get_page;
   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! The guy below you was faster, though your answer is better - more complex and I got it working just because of it.

Comment: glad to hear that, it's not complex i use a function to it reusable,

Comment: yes but there's full curl settings so I could copy paste it to see that it works. In my old curl settings I had CONNECTTIMEOUT set which made it malfunctioning.

Comment: you can add any more setting for this function as you want

Comment: I know, it just that timeout that prevented it to work. I didn't realize that it was that before you posted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need cURL to allow cookies to be saved. Try adding these lines to the cURL setup. For me this worked:

```
$cookie = dirname(__FILE__) . "\cookie.txt";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
```

Comment: ok my bad, had `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` set... It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) firefox plugin to check what is going on during page access. There can be redirections, cookie set etc. And then try to implement this behaviour with php curl (note: set user-agent as and other client headers the same as browser)